# ListView.Behaviors and Prism DelegateCommand<T> problems

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

After hours of searching and trying I couldn't get the following to work.

Expected behavior: Tap on a item in a list once, navigate to a page. Tap 2-3 times (or more) on the same item quickly, still open ONE page and not more.

I have managed to do this, but when using a generic DelegateCommand  it just won't work for some reason.
I'm using Xamarin.Forms (version 3.1.0.637273) and Prism (version 7.1.0.172-pre).

In my XAML I have a ListView with the following behavior and bindings:

```
<ListView 
     CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
     ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
     <ListView.Behaviors>
          <b:EventToCommandBehavior
               Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
               EventName="ItemTapped"
               EventArgsParameterPath="Item" />
     </ListView.Behaviors>
         <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                   <ViewCell>
                       ...
                   </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
         </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In my ViewModel I have:

```
private ObservableCollection<SomeModel> _myCollection;
public ObservableCollection<SomeModel> MyCollection
{
    get { return _myCollection; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _myCollection, value); }
}

private bool _canNavigate;
public bool CanNavigate
{
     get { return _canNavigate; }
     set { SetProperty(ref _canNavigate, value); }
}


private DelegateCommand<SomeModel> _myCommand;
public DelegateCommand<SomeModel> MyCommand =>
            _someModel ?? (_myCommand = new DelegateCommand<SomeModel>(ExecuteMethod, (parameter) => CanNavigate))
            .ObservesProperty(() => CanNavigate);

private async void ExecuteMethod(SomeModel parameter)
{
     CanNavigate = false;

     NavigationParameters parameters = new NavigationParameters($"?id={parameter.Id}");
     await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("SomeCoolPage", parameters);

     CanNavigate = true;
}
```

I have also tried other varients with like this for example with no luck:

```
private async void ExecuteCommand()
{
     if(CanNavigate)
     {
          CanNavigate = false;
          ...
          ...
          CanNavigate = true;
     }
}
```

This code works when I'm not using the generic version of the DelegateCommand.

If anyone can point me to what is it I'm doing wrong that would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Does your Observable colleciton consists of 'SomeModel'? It won't work otherwise. So you should have something like ObservableCollection<SomeModel>

Comment: Check [ListView.SelectionMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity)

Comment: @AndresCastro Yes my ObservableCollection is of type 'SomeModel' I have edited my question to make things more clear. I will post a sample project for this bug so that people can test it out.

Comment: I added a short Task.Delay(100);  after navigating in the method and it fixed my problem, still not really happy though.